# Azure Logic App - xpath for xml with namespace prefix

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In my logic app i am using xpath() function to get the value of . I have tried different xpaths but getting error

'The template language function 'xpath' parameters are invalid: the 'xpath' parameter must be a supported, well formed XPath expression. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xpath for usage details.'.

i have the following xml:

[image]

I have tried:

```
@xpath(xml(<YourMessage>), '/*[local-name()=\"Envelope\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]/*[local-name()=\"Body\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]')
@xpath(xml(<YourMessage>), 'string(/*[local-name()=\"Envelope\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]/*[local-name()=\"Body\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"])')
```

but getting the same error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off converting to JSON and working with the data in that format.  At least you can get rid of all the silly namespace complexities that way.

LogicApps is JSON focused internally so doing so would be slightly more 'correct' anyway.

You can find samples at: [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)

And an evaluator: [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/)

Comment: any chance you could post an example? I am relatively new to LogicApps

Comment: In a logic app, you can convert XML to JSON and then select from the resulting object, but that's only useful if you have a direct path to the value you need to extract. Logic Apps don't have a built-in JSONPath implementation (or jq or jsonata or ...).
Also beware of converting XML to JSON where you're expecting an array (eg. purchase order lines). If there's only one record, it'll be a JSON object rather than an array with a single item.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the namespace in your xpath using this expression:

```
@xpath(YOURBODY, '/*[local-name()=\"Envelope\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]/*[local-name()=\"Body\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]')
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have a look at the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I did what Johns-305 suggested.

```
json(<Output>)['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming to this late, but the error is because you've escaped the double-quotes in the designer (which automagically escapes double-quotes for you).

This is from the [Reference guide to expression functions for Azure Logic Apps and Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xpath):

> Important
>
> If you work in code view, escape the double quotation mark (`"`) by using the backslash character (`\`). For example, you need to use escape characters when you serialize an expression as a JSON string. However, if you're work in the Logic App Designer or expression editor, you don't need to escape the double quotation mark because the backslash character is added automatically to the underlying definition, for example:
>
> Code view: `xpath(xml(body('Http')), '/*[name()=\"file\"]/*[name()=\"location\"]')`
>
> Expression editor: `xpath(xml(body('Http')), '/*[name()="file"]/*[name()="location"]')`

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is the value of one of the internal nodes, you can try:

```
@xpath(<YourMessage>, 'string(/*[local-name()=\"Envelope\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]/*[local-name()=\"Body\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"]/*[name()=\"SearchByABNv201408Response\"]/*[name()=\"ABRPayloadSearchResults\"]/*[name()=\"Request\"]/*[name()=\"identifierSearchRequest\"]/*[name()=\"authenticationGUID\"])')
```

I hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have a look at the screenshot